# Retorno e resposta ao envio do email no layout

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Tenho um sistema de envio de Email que recebe o nome e o Email do banco de dados e faz o envio .

Porém quando eu chamo a função ele vai carregar todos os emails na tela com o seu resultado na frente.

```
teste@teste.com => enviado 
teste@teste.com => erro 
teste@teste.com => enviado
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até aqui tudo bem :)

Mais a minha duvida e o seguinte, preciso  integrar ao layout que e esse aqui .

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui no `Enviando msg pra caixa do ==> Aguardando ação` 
no **"Aguardando ação"** quero mostrar pra qual email está sendo enviado assim por diante a cada envio, ficando na seguinte forma:

```
Enviando msg pra caixa do ==> teste@gmail.com
```

Comment: Não estou conseguindo entender, o que você quer.

Comment: Editei ,agora poderia ver se consegue me entender ?

Comment: Olá Alencar, e bem vindo ao [pt.so], para que alguém consiga te ajudar, acredito que você precise colocar parte dos fontes onde estes dados são montados

Answer (score 2):

Acho que entendi o que você quer, agora. Que simplesmente mostre um **STATUS** da ação de **ENVIO DE EMAIL**. Existe várias formas de fazer isso, vou lhe dizer como eu faria.

Imagine uma **CARTA DE VENDA**:

> Olá, {NOME} esse é uma carta de venda, blaw, blaw, blaw, blaw, ...
>   blaw, blaw, blaw, blaw.

E você tem que enviar para uma lista de email. Agora imagine que você tem uma tabela com essa lista de email.

**TBL_EMAIL**

```
ID | NOME     | EMAIL             | STATUS
1  | Fulano   | fulado@mail.com   | 0
2  | Beutrano | beutrano@mail.com | 0
3  | Cicrano  | cicrano@mail.com  | 0
```

**Explicação do STATUS**

- 0 = AGUARDANDO ENVIO
- 1 = ENVIADO

Agora você precisa iniciar a ação e pegar um email para começar o envio do email. Com um **SELECT** irá precisa retorna apenas um endereço de email para ser enviado.

```
SELECT * FROM `TBL_EMAIL` WHERE `STATUS`=0 LIMIT 1
```

Assim só irá trazer um email por vez.

**FRONTEND**

Agora vamos para a frontend. Neste ponto precisara de uma pagina para que a ação seja mostrada e executada. Por exemplo *www.site.com.br/enviando.php* e nesta pagina terá um script em loop para acompanhar as ações.

**www.site.com.br/enviando.php**

```
<p id="status"></p>

<script>
    function realtime() {
        $.get("ajax-email.php", {}, function(data) {
            $("#status").html(data.email +' - ' data.status + '<br>');
        }).done(function () {
            // se não dizer que espere, apenas coloque 0 ou deixe apenas a função realtime()
            setTimeout(function() {
                realtime();
            }, 100);
        });
    }

    // função sendo chamada pela primera vez
    realtime();
</script>
```

**NA PAGINA *ajax-email.php***

Quando a ação de envio de email for acionada.

```
// Primeiro vc faz um select no email com o SQL que mencionei acima
// SELECT * FROM `TBL_EMAIL` WHERE `STATUS`=0 LIMIT 1

// Vo meio vc terá suas funções me metodos para enviar um email
$return = acao_enviar($nome, $email, $mensagem);

// verificando se deu certo o envio de email
if($return) {
    $status = 'Sucesso';

    // neste ponto vc muda o statos no banco de dados 
    // UPDATE TBL_EMAIL SET STATUS=1 WHERE ID=$id

} else {
    $erro = 1;
    $status = 'Erro';
}


// Por fim o retorno final da ação
die(json_encode(array(
    'erro'  => $errro,
    'email'  => $email,
    'status' => $status
)));
```

Na página deve aparecer assim:

```
fulado@mail.com - Sucesso
beutrano@mail.com - Erro
cicrano@mail.com - Sucesso
```

---

*Isso aqui está bem básico, mas é apenas para você ter uma ideia de como fazer e do que entendi*